# I want to change the image on its Longpress?(All the imageviews are in loop and created dynamically)

Tags: android

Do these things upto now:-

I want to change the image on its long press.and all my imageviews are in for loop.
I got all id's from todo setId() and getId() methods.
But when i do this, current image is not change while change its second one.

This is my code:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < i1; i++) {//my i1 is number of inputs (which is every time changeble)
image = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
image.setId(i);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bed1);
tables.addView(image);}
```

Image Longclick Listener code:-

```
image.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
int updateid=v.getId();
editor.putInt("updatedid",updateid).apply();
if(updateid==R.drawable.bed1){
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hall);
}

buttonGalleryOpen();//open the phone gallery
return false;

}
});
```

code for open image from gallery:-

```
public void buttonGalleryOpen()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        selectedphoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

        int updatedid=pref.getInt("updatedid",-1);
        if(updatedid==0) {
            image.setImageBitmap(selectedphoto);//here i setbitmap.
        }


        cursor.close();


    }

}
```

This is my full code,please suggest if anything wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Add "image.setTag(R.drawable.bed1);" in the for-loop.
2. Modify onLongClick():

   ```
   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
       image = (ImageView) v;
       int updateid = v.getId();
       editor.putInt("updatedid",updateid).apply();
       int imgId = 0;
       if(v.getTag() != null) imgId = (Integer) v.getTag(); 
       if(imgId == R.drawable.bed1){
           image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hall);
           image.setTag(R.drawable.hall);
       }
       buttonGalleryOpen();//open the phone gallery
       return true;
   }
   ```
3. Change "if(updatedid == 0) {" to "if(updatedid >= 0) {" in OnActivityResult().

Hope this help!

Comment: I got null pointer exception on int imgId = (int) v.getTag(); this line